# How can server PC access the SQL Server data of Clients PC using Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have  more than 100 clients on different networks (not on LAN) e.g. one is in USA and other in UK and other in Dubai and so on.
My all clients PC using the same Windows application and their own local DB.and using internet with Router.as you know due to router public IP always change after 24 hour.

My server PC is in Australia and server is using web application.

Client PC can get access server PC using Windows Services. 
But my question: how  server  pc will get the data from client PC's using web services or any in your mind?
Please give any good Idea with example of sample code, please don't give me any huge theoretical link to read. I want just sample code which I will write in my server side Web application and it will fetch data from clients PC .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server can't fetch data from clients because off firewalls and dynamic IPs (which you pointed out).  I think the clients will have to upload the data to the server.  Can you tell us more about the "Windows Services" that enable the client to communicate with the server?  Perhaps you can use this t allow clients to upload data to the server?

Comment: you are right but i want server also could get data from client or push data..i mean duplex commuication.

Comment: As others have said, the client needs to initiate a connection with the server.  So the client needs to be enhanced to do this on a regular basis.  I gather you have a web server?  Can you enhance the client to upload the data to the server?

Comment: i was trying to initiate from client,and did same as you said .its working on same network but if i use different network server ip then its not response me... if you want i can show you code

Comment: So when the client and server are on the same network, things work fine, but when the client accesses the server across the internet it doesn't work?  If so, then you have a connectivity/networking/entitlement/security issue.

Comment: Yes you got a problem . but how to handle this situation please??

Comment: problem is that :eg. i make my pc server and you make your pc client. in client.cs file you'll put my pc external ip. in that case its will no work ... exactly that's a problem ..

Comment: At this point I think you have a networking issue which should be raised elsewhere.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You will more likely to succeed with syncing the clients with your server, not the other way round.

Syncing with the clients will bring about a whole host of security and configuration issues.

The opposite is a single server that all clients communicate with and send data.

Comment: i am sorry i am not clear understand you, can you little explain in  simple way,,,how can i syncing the clients with my server??

Comment: Are you talking about Singal R??

Comment: Start doing some research `Tariqu_ASp.net`

Comment: DJ Kraze ,I'm doing Research Since yesterday.But I've not find any right solution. Can you briefly give me any idea to solve this issue??? please,,